# Can I use JTA manager for IgniteThinClient?

Tags: java, caching, ignite, jta, thin

I use thin client for caches. I need to attach a JTA transaction manager to thinClient. Can Ignite ThinClient use a JTA transaction manager? I couldn't find a property for setting JTA manager in ClientTransactionConfiguration. TransactionConfiguration has a function setTxManagerFactory to set transaction manager JTA factory, but TransactionConfiguration isn't compatible with ThinClient, it applies to fat IgniteClient.

```
public ClientTransactionConfiguration transactionConfiguration() {
    final ClientTransactionConfiguration configuration = new ClientTransactionConfiguration();
    // configuration.setTxManagerFactory(webSphereTmFactory());
    configuration.setDefaultTxIsolation(TransactionIsolation.READ_COMMITTED);
    configuration.setDefaultTxConcurrency(TransactionConcurrency.PESSIMISTIC);
    //  configuration.setUseJtaSynchronization(true);
    return configuration;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you need to use a thick-client if you want to participate in JTA transactions.